# SWT DragSourceEvent image not anchored to mouse pointer correctly

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt, jface, treeviewer

I have the following issue when I drag and drop from a tree viewer in SWT. I am setting the image attribute of the `dragSourceEvent` e.g.

```
event.image = _dragImage
```

which works fine EXCEPT for instances where I have a long label on my tree viewer node. If I have a long string and start the drag event from the far right edge of the caption on the node, I notice that the drag image is not correctly anchored and is actually offset X pixels according to the distance from the start of the tree node string to the end of the tree node string.

Anyone any suggestions? Yee would probably have to demo to get an idea of it. Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot (at least the link to one) and an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of starting the drag operation from the far right of the tree item label (shown) - you will see the ghost image of the hardware I am dragging and dropping NOT correctly anchored to the mouse pointer. The difference from the XOffset of the pointer is roughly the starting point of the label to the end of the label. See link:

http://s28.postimg.org/qzf41xxzx/screenshot.png

Answer (score 0):

If you set the fields `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY` to `0`, it will put the top-left of the image exactly on the mouse pointer.

If you set them to `100`, it will put the top-left of the image 100 pixels to the left and above the mouse pointer.

SWT pre-populates these numbers in an attempt to get your image to line up with the offset of your original click.  Not sure why it's not working in your case.